# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') error

Tags: javascript, checkbox, addeventlistener, createelement

I have such a JavaScript

```js
const checkBox = document.createElement("input")
checkBox.className = "form-check-input me-1 fa-pull-right"
checkBox.type = "checkbox"
li.appendChild(checkBox);
checkBox.id = "checkBox";


checkBox.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (checkBox.checked) {
    li.setAttribute = ("id", "completed");
  } else
    li.removeAttribute = ("id", "completed");
});
```

code to create an input and when its checked add a style id tag to add line through but i am getting this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')"

Comment: `document.querySelector("#checkBox")` isn't finding anything.

Comment: Since you already set the variable using `document.createElement()`, why do you need to do it again with `querySelector()`?

Comment: These codes can't be in the same scope as you show here, since you can't declare a variable twice with `const`. Most likely the second code is running before the first code, so the checkbox hasn't been added yet to the DOM.

Comment: how can i trigger the second code line after i created the checkbox. i see second code line runs even before checkbox hasnt been created.

Comment: I made a snippet of your supplied code but since you supplied no HTML it fails.  Perhaps add that as a working minimal example that reproduces your issue..  Note `li` is undefined here in your supplied code.

Comment: The variable "li" is not declared or defined anywhere, so lets do that, `const li = document.querySelector("li");` still you need li element within html to append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the issues with your code are:

- The variable `li` is not defined or declared.
- `setAttribute` is a function and not an assignment, it cannot be used with equal signs.
- A `li` element is required within the DOM to append.

I have made the following changes to address the issues in your code:

- Added the `var li` declaration.
- Added a `li` element within the HTML for appending.
- Lastly, Equal sign is removed so that when the checkbox is checked, the id `completed` will be added to the `li` element.

```js
const li = document.querySelector("li");
const checkBox = document.createElement("input")
checkBox.className = "form-check-input me-1 fa-pull-right"
checkBox.type = "checkbox"
checkBox.id = "checkBox";
li.appendChild(checkBox);

checkBox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (checkBox.checked) {
    li.setAttribute("id", "completed");
    console.log(li)
  } else
    li.removeAttribute("id", "completed");
});
```

```html
<li></li>
```